# Functions aren't executed

Tags: kernel, built-in-symbols

Can't figure out why Mathematica doesn't want to execute  built-in functions? What can be wrong?

[image]

Input:

```
Convolve[1/(x - t)^(3/2)*Exp[-gamma/(2 (x - t))], 1/t^(3/2)*Exp[-gamma/(2 t)], t, x]
```

Output:

```
Convolve[E^(-(gamma/(2 (-t + x))))/(-t + x)^(3/2), E^(-(gamma/(2 t)))/t^(3/2), t, x]
```

Input:

```
Integrate[(1/(x - t)^(3/2)*Exp[-gamma/(2 (x - t))])*(1/t^(3/2)*
Exp[-gamma/(2 t)]), t]
```

Output:

```
\[Integral]E^(-(gamma/(2 t)) - gamma/(2 (-t + x)))/(t^(3/2) (-t + x)^(3/2)) \[DifferentialD]t
```

Comment: Likely, that means *Mathematica* doesn't know a closed-form solution, if it exists.

Comment: And when asking questions, post code rather than pictures of code so that people can copy and paste the code into a workbook.

Comment: @BobHanlon, thanks for advice, I have added source code too and will do it further.

Answer (score 3):

The problem that you having with your problem is that the convolution envelope does not converge well when approaching zero. The best way is tackle this is to add a step function. This way will force all  envelope to be zero for all negative numbers.
Inspecting the envelope with Gamma = 1
    Plot[1/t^(3/2)*Exp[-1/(2 t)] UnitStep[t], {t, -2, 2}]

[image]

Follow up with the convolution

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

Convolve[1/(x - t)^(3/2)*Exp[-\[CapitalGamma]/(2 (x - t))], 
 1/t^(3/2)*Exp[-\[CapitalGamma]/(2 t)] UnitStep[t], t, x]
```

The result is 
$
\frac{1}{\Gamma ^2}
$